# Create PostgreSQL ODBC Excel table

Tags: qgis, postgresql, excel, connection, qgis-cloud

I want to allow a non-GIS user edit a CSV file which is hosted on QGIS Cloud on a PostGIS database. My method is to load the table from the QGIS Cloud database into Excel via ODBC.

Here are my steps so far:

1. Downloaded the psqlodbc installation file from [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) (64 bit).
2. Opened the control panel | Administrative Tools | ODBC Data Sources (64-bit).
   Strangely only 34 bit is available here....
3. User DSN | Add | PostgreSQL ANSI | Finish (see screenshot)
   [image]
4. Input database details as per [QGIS Cloud connection FAQ](https://support.qgiscloud.com/kb/faq.php?id=4)
   [image][image]
5. When testing the connection:

[image]

Comment: at step 4, you specified host=localhost, which would work only if you are running this on the machine that contains Postgres. You may want to try with `db.qgiscloud.com` instead

Comment: Thanks @JGH that solved it...

Comment: [ODBC](https://www.devart.com/odbc/what-is-an-odbc-driver.html) is hugely popular among application developers as it allows to write a single application to access data in relational and non-relational data sources from different vendors.